# File Date to Exif Data

Tags: photo, exif, properties-file

I have a bunch of old folders containing photos from 2000s.
For an unknown reason photos are empty of Exif data.
But I want, at least, to keep the dates of each photo. So that they are in order when I import them in iCloud Photos.

Is there a software, or in command line way, or a script in any programming language, able to take each date inside 'file properties' and insert it in the photos' Exif data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean *"each date inside 'file properties' "* please? What are *"file properties"* and how many dates are in there?  And which one(s) do you want?

Comment: Hi, I'm taking about these properties: https://i.gyazo.com/a1f2d72244fd539ff08992a256ba91cd.png 15/09/2014 is the date at which was taken my picture. However, it's a property of the file in Windows File Explorer, but it's not in the EXIF metadata...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `exiftool`. **Make a backup of your files first**, then try this on a single file:

```
exiftool "-alldates<filecreatedate" ONEIMAGE.jpg
```

Then check your *"file properties"* that you refer to and also check with:

```
exiftool ONEIMAGE.jpg
```

If that all looks correct, you can do all files in a directory like this:

```
exiftool "-alldates<filecreatedate" DIRECTORYNAME
```

Comment: Thanks. However, it's not working when I type what you gave me exiftool's program quits without changing the date... Here's a GIF of what goes on: https://i.gyazo.com/56e0d8fc0382bee2cf39bb27a8897959.mp4 If I'm typing it wrong please advise how you I do it. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were on Windows - I assumed you were on a Mac using iCloud. I have no idea where Microsoft gets that information from. I'll leave my answer as it is potentially useful to Mac and Linux users. Maybe add the `windows` tag to your question.

Comment: Okay I tried on my Mac and it's a lot easier thanks! Although your command line does not work. Here is the date I wanna keep: https://i.imgur.com/cX6cAkB.png the modification date, of 2014. But when I run your command line it gives today's date: https://i.imgur.com/OPJelmi.png

Comment: Try changing `filecreatedate` to `FileModifyDate`

Comment: It does work! Thank you very much! However, it only works for .jpg, do you have a second command line to make it work with .png please?

Comment: I think @StarGeek has the answer for that for you here... https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/64560

Comment: Their solution there doesn't work. I'm getting this error message: "Warning: Sorry, png:DateTimeOriginal doesn't exist or isn't writable -". Maybe because I'm on Mac...